# Can I use UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert when the table is not in edit mode?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table that includes an "add object" cell at the bottom. The behaviour I would like is to have that cell use the insert style (i.e., display the + on the left) all the time, not just when the table is in edit mode. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The green + (insert) or red - (delete) only appear when the table is in edit mode.

Do you do anything else when actually in edit mode? If not, just put the table view in edit mode all of the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do allow deletion & rearranging in edit mode. Adding to this table is just so common I wanted to save the user the step of editing first. Will add a button then. Thanks!